# mq_receive gives "Message too long" error in NASM

Tags: linux, posix, nasm, message-queue

The NASM code below is a very simplified version of a much larger program.  It is a shared object, not an .exe; its entry point is Main_Entry_fn.  It uses POSIX message queues.  The program operates on two cores.  The first core calls the section "Write_Data_To_Memory_fn" where it receives and processes messages.  The second core calls the section "While_Loop_Test_fn" where it processes data and sends messages.

For the purpose of this example, the core instantiation has been removed because the section "While_Loop_Test_fn" (which includes mq_send) has been bypassed -- first I need to set up the mq_receive to prepare to receive messages.

The message queue is successfully created, and successfully opened in the section "Write_Data_To_Memory_fn" but the problem is that mq_receive fails with the message "Message too long."

The message length is defined in the mq_msgsize node of the attributes structure as 656 bytes.  The MQ_Receive_Buffer is defined as 82 quadwords for 656 bytes.  The third parameter passed to mq_receive is also 656 bytes.

The Linux man page at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_receive.3.html says, "The msg_len argument specifies the size of the buffer pointed to by msg_ptr; this must be greater than or equal to the mq_msgsize attribute of the queue."  Here, all references to the output buffer are 656 bytes.

Here is the NASM code:

```
; Header Section
[BITS 64]

[default rel]

global Main_Entry_fn
global While_Loop_Test_fn
global Write_Data_To_Memory_fn
extern mq_open, mq_close, mq_unlink, mq_send, mq_receive,   mq_getattr, perror

%define O_RDONLY     00000000
%define O_WRONLY 00000001
%define O_RDWR 00000002
%define O_CREAT 00000100

section .data align=16
vector_of_8s: times 82 dq 0
MQ_Name: db "/MQ_01",0x00
MQ_FDes: dq 0
MQ_FDes_Core: dq 0
MQ_FDes_Core_02: dq 0
MQ_Receive_Buffer: times 82 dq 0
msg_priority: dq 0
perror_msg: db "Error Number\n"

struc mq_attr
  .mq_flags: resd 1
  .mq_maxmsg: resd 1
  .mq_msgsize: resd 1
  .mq_curmsgs: resd 1
endstruc

mq_attributes:
  istruc mq_attr
    at mq_attr.mq_flags, dd O_RDWR
    at mq_attr.mq_maxmsg, dd 100
    at mq_attr.mq_msgsize, dd 656
    at mq_attr.mq_curmsgs, dd 0
  iend

; __________

section .text

Init_Cores_fn:

; __________
; Set up POSIX message queue

Message_queue:

mov rax,O_RDWR
mov rbx,O_CREAT
or rax,rbx
mov rdi,MQ_Name
mov rsi,rax
mov rdx,777 ; mode
mov rcx,mq_attr
call mq_open wrt ..plt
mov [MQ_FDes],rax

jmp Write_Data_To_Memory_fn

; ______________________________________

While_Loop_Test_fn:

; This section is bypassed for the MCRE example
; It is included here to show how messages are sent with 
mq_send

Open_message_queue:
lea rdi,[MQ_Name]
mov rsi,O_RDWR
call mq_open wrt ..plt
mov [MQ_FDes_Core],rax

; IPC MESSAGE IS SENT HERE
mov rsi,vector_of_8s ; MQ_Message
mov [rsi+80],rbx ;core number

mov rdi,[MQ_FDes_Core]
mov rsi,MQ_Receive_Buffer
mov rax,199
mov [rsi],rax
mov rdx,96
mov rcx,msg_priority

call mq_send wrt ..plt

; __________

label_900:

; Close message queue
mov rdi,[MQ_FDes]
call mq_close wrt ..plt
lea rdi,[MQ_Name]
call mq_unlink wrt ..plt

ret

; __________
; Main Entry

Main_Entry_fn:

push rdi
push rbp
push rbx

call Init_Cores_fn

pop rbx
pop rbp
pop rdi
ret

;__________

Write_Data_To_Memory_fn:

lea rdi,[MQ_Name]
mov rsi,O_RDONLY
mov rdx,777
mov rcx,mq_attr
call mq_open wrt ..plt
mov [MQ_FDes_Core_02],rax

mov rdi,[MQ_FDes_Core_02]
mov rsi,MQ_Receive_Buffer
mov rdx,656
mov rcx,msg_priority
call mq_receive wrt ..plt ; MQ CALL

cmp rax,-1
jne no_error
mov rdi,perror_msg
call perror wrt ..plt
no_error:

jmp label_900

ret
```

As all references to the message buffer size are the same, why am I getting the error "message too long."

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The man page for the mq_attr structure shows that the fields within the structure are all longs, you have them defined as dd which if dq is 8 bytes will be 4 bytes so should these be 8 bytes rather than 4 bytes?  You don't say what architecture your running this on so 4 bytes might be right.

Comment: After changing the struc elements to dq I can now access the struc elements in rax instead of eax, but I still have the "Message too long" error when I call mq_receive.